# Content does not contain updates

Tags: contentful

We use Contentful's webhook for triggering an external build process. Every now and then we notice, when this webhook is fired after publishing content changes, these changes are not visible after the build is finished. In these cases we have to start the process manually which fixes the issue.

According to Contentful, since the delivery API is powered by a CDN, it takes some time (up to 5 minutes) to reflect changes.

Is it possible to flush/invalidate the content first before downloading the content from Contentful. Or is the content available through another url i.o. cdn.contentful.com and give me the 'original' content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to flush the caches faster, because that process is already in progress after changing your content — it simply takes some time.

What you could do, is using the Content Management API to fetch the content, but you have to keep two things in mind:

1. There's a much stricter rate limit in place for the CMA
2. You will also receive unpublished content when using the CMA

The CMA also has only limited querying capabilities, see https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference for the full documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I think I just add a delay soort the invoked proces to ensure the updated content is retrieved. Almost instantly :)